# Time derivative of an observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was reading from P.C. Martin "Measurements and Correlation Functions" and I got stuck on a detail: in the section about the Sum Rules he writes that

$$
\frac{1}{\hbar} \langle \left[ i\frac{d^n\hat{A}_i(\vec{r},t)}{dt^n} , \hat{A}_j(\vec{r}',t') \right] \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d\omega}{\pi} \omega^n\hat{\chi}''_{ij}(\vec{r},\vec{r}',\omega)
$$

which he then follows with

$$
\frac{1}{\hbar} \langle \left[ \left[ \left[ \left[ \hat{A}_i(\vec{r},t) ,\hat{H}/\hbar \right] , \hat{H}/\hbar \right] \dots \right] , \hat{A}_j(\vec{r}',t') \right] \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d\omega}{\pi} \omega^n\hat{\chi}''_{ij}(\vec{r},\vec{r}',\omega).
$$

This would be true if $\hat{A}_i(\vec{r},t)$ was time-independent, which I don't believe to be true given the generality of the presentation. What am I missing?